# Magento: include php files in same directory. Failed to open stream

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I receive the following errors in system.log:

```
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Paylike\Adapter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Paylike\Adapter.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/local:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/community:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/core:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib:.:/usr/local/share/pear')  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Paylike\Transaction.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Paylike\Transaction.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/local:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/community:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/core:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib:.:/usr/local/share/pear')  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Paylike\Card.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Paylike\Card.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/local:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/community:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/core:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib:.:/usr/local/share/pear')  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Paylike\Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-01-25T11:53:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Paylike\Client.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/local:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/community:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/app/code/core:/usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib:.:/usr/local/share/pear')  in /usr/local/www/prostorage5/xx/xx/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I tested if it's looking the correct directory and it does.

This is first part of the php code of Client.php:

```
<?php
namespace Paylike;
include_once( 'Adapter.php' );
include_once( 'Transaction.php' );
include_once( 'Card.php' );
```

Anyone knows why it says failed to open stream: no such file or directory? Adapter.php, Transaction.php and Card.php are in the same directory as Client.php. Also tested replacing **( '** with **__DIR__ . '/**

Comment: Have you checked the permission of the files?<br>
Maybe it's only a permission issue.

Comment: Is this class inside a Magento module? or /lib folder? or what? :)

Comment: You can check https://github.com/paylike/plugin-magento-1.9 for the module.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to rewrite this code (classes in Model/api dir) as Magento module models. Then you can access them using:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('namespace/module_model');
```

Otherwise you can put them into /lib/**ModuleName** catalog, call them like that:

```
new ModuleName_Client();
```

and then probably:

```
include_once( 'Adapter.php' );
```

won't be no longer neccessary - Magento (Zend) autoloader should find them.